# separate string in two by given position

Tags: php, string

```
$string = 'Some string';
$pos = 5;

...??...

$begging // == 'Some s';
$end // == 'tring';
```

What is the best way to separate string in two by given position?

Comment: How comes the position? Did you calculated its value based on the `$string`?

Comment: There are alternative answers given. What did you mean by "best way"? fastest? least code?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use [`substr`](http://php.net/substr) to get the two sub-strings:

```
$str1 = substr($str, 0, $pos);
$str2 = substr($str, $pos);
```

If you omit the third parameter *length*, `substr` takes the rest of the string.

But to get your result you actually need to add one to `$pos`:

```
$string = 'Some string';
$pos = 5;
$begin = substr($string, 0, $pos+1);
$end = substr($string, $pos+1);
```

Comment: Beware when dealing with multibyte strings!

Comment: By using `$pos+1` you're omitting a character.  Given a $pos of 5, you'll wind up with `"Some "` and `"tring"`

Comment: @Gumbo My first instinct was to add a similar comment on Tim's answer telling him he was doing it wrong by *not* using `$pos+1` :) +1 for the fixed-up answer at any rate

Answer (score 38):

Regex solution (if you are into it):

```
...
$string = 'Some string xxx xxx';
$pos = 5;

list($beg, $end) = preg_split('/(?<=.{'.$pos.'})/', $string, 2);

echo "$beg - $end";
```

Regards

rbo

Comment: convince people of the advantage of your solution over the `substr` way.

Comment: There is only one way to settle this... Quick! Someone do a benchmark performance test and compare the results!

Comment: I love one-liners :3

Comment: @rubberboots no you just say to use a canon to kill a mosquito :P

Comment: In my testing the regex was an order of 5 times faster than the substr (7.7009201049805E-5 vs 0.12504506111145 milliseconds)

Comment: @rubberboots it's because people do not understand it. Do not make big head because of it, your solution is great. I like people who save numbers of rows in code. Thanks

Comment: I prefer this solution as it gives back an array similar to explode() would but position based.

Comment: Thank you for your solution.  I love that it is different, faster, returns an array and does not use substr().  You rock!

Comment: Modify the regex to `/\s*(?<=.{'.$pos.'})\s*/` if you want to strip spaces while you're at it.

Comment: @rubberboots I need a bit more help on regex, I know if I want 3 substrings I can simply change `2` to `3` in the func, but what if the first substring needs another length? e.g. `yyyymmdd` to `yyyy-mm-dd`

Answer (score 3):

How about substr()?

```
$string = 'Some string';
$pos = 5;

$beginning = substr($string, 0, $pos);
$end = substr($string, $pos);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Wordwrap](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) works better in my opinion.

```
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");
echo $newtext;
```

The above example will output:

```
The quick brown fox<br />
jumped over the lazy<br />
dog.
```

Another example:

```
$text = "A very long woooooooooooord.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 8, "\n", true);

echo "$newtext\n";
```

The above example will output:

```
A very
long
wooooooo
ooooord.
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to separate
>   string in two by given position?

If i understand you correctly, you can do:

```
$str = 'hello world';
$pos = 5;

$separated_str = substr($str, $pos);
echo $separated_str;
```

**Result:**

```
world
```

This depends on the structure of your string as there are other ways also to split the string.

Comment: this does does not applies to OP question "separate string in two by given position" also you said, "This depends on the structure of your string as there are other ways also to split the string", can you re-edit?

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for a fast a way to split a string at a given position.

Why a given position? Usually what you need is to split against a character (I think you searched by position because the explode function would split the string in too much pieces):

My solution was finally:

```
$string = "hello world my dear";
list ($first, $remaining ) = split (' ', $string, 2); //limit to 2 pieces
echo $first; //"hello";
echo $remaining; //"world my dear";
```

Notice that I dropped the use of "position" (I was using "substr" to get it).

Given that your need for "position" was not really necessary, my solution is the fastest among all others above and does not have multi-byte issues. Also I think it is much easier to read.

Unluckily that function is deprecated in last PHP, you can use it if you have old PHP or you can use preg_split. I was not very happy of that because the only way to achieve same functionality is abusing regex. In case you cannot use `split` the fastest alternative is:

```
$string = "hello world my dear";
list ($first, $remaining ) =  preg_split('/\s+/', $string, 2);
```

wich is much faster than @rubber answer and does not use position at all.

Reference:
[Split documentation](http://php.net/manual/it/function.split.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = 'Some string';
$pos = 6;
$number_of_pieces = 2;
list($beginning, $end) = split_into_pieces($string, $pos, $number_of_pieces);
// $beginning === 'Some s'; $end === 'tring'

function split_into_pieces($string, $length, $limit = 0) {
  --$length;
  return preg_split("/(?<=^..{{$length}}|(?!^)\\G.{{$length}})/", $text, $limit);
}
```

- `$string` is the string to split
- `$length` is the size of each piece in Unicode code-points (or ASCII characters if not using the UTF-8 option, see below). Any value less than `1` will return the entire input string as a single piece
- `$limit` is the maximum number or pieces, or `0` for unlimited. The final piece will contain the remainder of the string and might be longer or shorter than `$length`

The regex that is doing the magic is using a positive look-behind `(?<=` ... `)`. It looks for `^`, which is the start of the string, `|` or if it's not at the beginning of the string `(?!^)` it looks for `\G`, which is the position of the previous match. `.` is any character, `{` *n* `}` is repeated *n* times, where *n* is `{$length}`. When using `\G`, it adds an extra character for some reason, which is why there's the line `--$length;` and why the first match has an extra `.` to search for an extra code-point, which is not usually allowed in look-behinds. I think the zero-width assertions `^` and `\G` are anchoring the pattern, allowing different lengths in the look-behind.

The extra `{` and `}` around `$length` are necessary to stop the regex braces being interpreted as an escaped PHP variable. `/su` are the regex options. The `/s` option says allow `.` to match newline characters. The `/u` option says to match Unicode code-points encoded as UTF-8 (remove `u` if you are parsing strings that are non-UTF-8 compliant).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
Function Splp($S,...$A){ #Split At Positions 
    $k = 0;
    $R = [];
    $A[] = Strlen($S);
    Foreach($A As $a){
        $R[] = Substr($S,$k,$a-$k);
        $k = $a;
    }
    Return $R;}

$string = 'Some string';
$pos1 = 5;
$pos2 = 7;
[$Start,$Mid,$End] = Splp($string,$pos1,$pos2);
echo $Start,', ',$Mid,', ',$End; #  Some , st, ring
?>
```