# array_pop for string in PHP?

Tags: php, string

Pop the last x bytes of a string off the string and return it. Any classic way to do it in PHP other than a custom function like this?

```
function string_pop(&$str, $num) {
    $pop = substr($str, - $num);
    $str = substr($str, 0, strlen($str) - $num);
    return $pop;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [separate string in two by given position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449348/separate-string-in-two-by-given-position)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like

```
list($str, $pop) = str_split($str, strlen($str) - $num);
```

*EDIT*: As pointed out by Gergo Erdosi, this code will only work if the `$num` is less than half of the length of `$str`. The following would work otherwise.

```
$arr = str_split($str, strlen($str) - $num);

$pop = array_pop($arr);
$str = implode('', $arr);
```

But whether or not this is more elegant than you're original function is debatable.

Comment: Run your code with these variables: `$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'; $num = 20;`.

Comment: Ah yes, my code only works when $num is less than half of the string length

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the most efficient, but here is a one liner:

```
list($str, $pop) = preg_split('/(?<=.{'.(strlen($str) - $num).'})/', $str, 2);
```