# Splitting up a string with no common delimiter

Tags: php

I am trying to split up a string like this:

> 22/9 14 ALTERNATE (16) myXMG fe (2)infernoHitbox Arena

I want to get `22/9 14` then `ALTERNATE` then `(16)` etc. But also need to split `(2)` `inferno` and `Hitbox Arena`. Problem is theres no common delimter across the string to get all these out. Also, I will need to split other strings in a similar fashion. Same order of information, just different content..

I'm struggling for ideas. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: then you need to use a regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works only with a regular Expression. You could work with [substr](http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php) but that only works if the positions are the same.

So you should have a look at [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Answer (score 0):

If all the data you got has the same Character indexes.

You should try this method
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

And also found one here with a similar question
[separate string in two by given position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449348/separate-string-in-two-by-given-position)