# PHP how to add variable string after strpos

Tags: php, string, variables, strpos

I am getting all the data of a webpage then searching it for a certain string. I use strpos to find the location, then once found i would like to create a variable that stores all the information 64 characters past the strpos.

E.g:

$begin = strpos($page, 'content123') //Then once position is found on webpage, add another 64 characters beyond the 3 (of 123)

To clarify, i am getting file contents from a web page, searching the page data for a position (e.g 'content), then once i have found the position, I would like the program to grab everything after this marker by 64 characters (this is a variable)

EDIT:

```
$begin = strpos($page, 'https://i2.au.reastatic.net/800x600/') + strlen('https://i2.au.reastatic.net/800x600/'); 
$end   = strpos($page, '/image.jpg');
$ImageName = substr($page, $begin, ($end - $begin));

$ImageContent = 'https://i2.au.reastatic.net/800x600/' . $ImageName . '/image.jpg';
```

P.S, not sure why people are down voting a legitimate question? I thought this was a place to help each other.

Thanks

Comment: what's the issue here ? what prevent you from going further ? substr (or mb_substr if dealing with utf8 strings) with `$begin + strlen('content123')` and 64 as length should be enough

Comment: Both of your last questions have asked for an example of the text you need to work with and yet to have a response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [separate string in two by given position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449348/separate-string-in-two-by-given-position)

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449348/separate-string-in-two-by-given-position

Comment: thanks for the replies, i have tried both suggestions and they dont work either, i am adding code to main text so you can see what i had done originally but i get nothing when the code runs.

Comment: As asked for several times, what is the content of `$page`

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your code is correct

```
$page = 'https://i2.au.reastatic.net/800x600/ImageName/image.jpg';
$begin = strpos($page, 'https://i2.au.reastatic.net/800x600/') + strlen('https://i2.au.reastatic.net/800x600/');
$end   = strpos($page, '/image.jpg');
$ImageName = substr($page, $begin, ($end - $begin));
$ImageContent = 'https://i2.au.reastatic.net/800x600/' . $ImageName . '/image.jpg';
echo $ImageContent;
```